# Schroedinger equation. Mass. Charge

Tags: schroedinger-equation

The mass of a particle appears in Schroedinger equation but it does not appear its charge, although both terms have their effect on movement.Why?

Comment: You could say the same thing about $F=ma$.

Comment: Check out e.g. [the hydrogen atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hamiltonian involves potential energy! So the effect of charge is inherently involved in the Schrodinger equation. If you write down the time dependent Schrodinger Equation, you will see that.

Answer (score 4):

The Hamiltonian for a particle with charge $q$ is $$H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} (\nabla - q\vec A)^2  + q\phi$$
where $\vec A$ is the vector potential and $\phi$ the scalar potential. So the charge appears explicitly.